# How to add Option Menu to the Gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, optionmenu

I want to add a Option menu to the Gallery, but not as a part of "Share-Via". I was able to add menu to the Share-Via.
What I am looking for is adding the menu to the Option menu to "More" menu.
I have tried almost everything but the menu doesn't get added.
Any pointers would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add an options menu item to the Gallery application, as that is not your application.

Comment: How the Whatsapp appear in `Set as` option? Here is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964671/android-adding-an-app-to-set-picture-as-list). thanx

Answer (score 4):

just add the following lines into your manifest corresponding to the activity that should open on clicking the option on share menu.....

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```