# Android: adding an app to "set picture as" list

Tags: android

I'm trying to add my app to "set as" list, that shown in gallery when I choose an image. If the user open an image in the gallery, there is a button for `set as`. when the user tap it, he will get a list. In other words, if he want to use that image in my app. 
I have tried :

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

but i got nothing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now i've understand:
You have to register your Activity to handle Images input from other apps.
Insert this in your Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

More infos on [Develop>Training>Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: sorry if you misunderstand, I don't want my app in PICK list, I want it in `set as` list.

Comment: Do you have     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
?

Comment: No, I don't want to change the wallpaper. If the user open an image in the gallery, there is a button for `set as`. when the user tap it, he will get a list. In other words, if he want to use that image in my app.

Comment: I'm so sorry. This code for `Share` button not `Set as`. see the first image. when i tap `More`, there is a menu. and one of its items is `Set as`. that what I'm looking for. but thank you for wasting your time trying help me.

Answer (score 0):

The `intent-filter` to add out own app to the list in Gallery and Photos app for "use as" or "set picture as" is `ATTACH_DATA`.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```