# When we open gallery there is an option "Set Picture as" and we can set as contact picture or wallpaper.how can we achieve this from our app

Tags: android

(in this link you can see that option) [Android: adding an app to "set picture as" list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964671/android-adding-an-app-to-set-picture-as-list])

1. I want to achieve the functionality from my app that you achieve from the gallery(functionality of "set picture as").

i didn't find solution for it.

Comment: Here's for you to get started: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: i've made my custom gallery,fetched image from camera,or gallery too.but not able to achieve that functionality.